# Automorphism group of moduli space $M_{0,n}$

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, teichmuller-theory

**Statement:**  *the group of complex automorphisms of the moduli space $M_{0,n}$ of complex $n$-marked genus 0 curves is isomorphic to $\mathfrak S_n$: one has ${\rm Aut}(M_{0,n})=\mathfrak S_n$*

I believe that this is true for $n\geq 5$ (what about the cases $n=3,4$?) and has been obtained in the 50's by peoples working in Teichmuller theory.

**Questions:**

1. Is this statement correct ?
2. If it is, who has to be credited for it?

Classical/canonical references as well as recent but very useful/relevant references are welcome !

Thanks in advance

---

**Remark:** if $\overline{M}_{0,n}$ stands for Deligne-Mumford-Knudsen moduli space of stable $n$-marked genus 0 curves, that ${\rm Aut}(\overline{M}_{0,n})=\mathfrak S_n$ has been proved only recently (in **[A. Bruno, M. Mella]**: *The automorphism group of $\overline{M}_{0,n}$*, J. Eur. Math. Soc., Volume 15 (2013), pp. 949-968).

Comment: $M_{0,3}$ is a point, so its automorphism group is trivial. $M_{0,4}$ is a projective line minus $3$ points, so its automorphism group is $S_3$.